# Improving performance of an Entity Framework linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We are using views in Entity Framework. When I execute the programview in SQL Server, it was rendered quickly with in 2 seconds. I have created simple linq query / lambda expression to get the output in or application  but it is taking more than 2 minutes to get the final result. I am not sure how the same view is running quickly in backend (SQL Server), creating problem when I use it via Entity Framework.

C#

```
  this.db.progamview.Where(x =>
                            x.pId== 6&&
                              x.qId== 12
                             && x.RId== 20151
                            && x.cId== 102)
```

I have tried to set the timeout but still it is not worked. what are the ways we can improve the performance in Entity Framework when we handling the large data sets or how to handle the views in EF which retrieving large datasets?

Tried `AsNotracking` method like below, but no luck.

```
this.db.progamview.Where(x => x.pId== 6 && x.qId== 12 && x.RId== 20151 && x.cId== 
102).AsNoTracking();

Version: EF6.1
```

It is returning  18 columns. I need all the columns to display in front-end.

Tried below methodologies, but still am getting output too late. i.e. taking 4-5 minutes to give the result.

1. timeout property in context
2. `AsNotracking` method

Client statistics screenshot below

[image]

Any other better way to improve the performance ?

Comment: how many columns and rows does sql server return? and how much bytes is being transferred?

Comment: @fredou updated question

Comment: could you provide the exact number? can you post a screenshot of the client statistic? (from sql management studio)

Comment: @fredou it is returning 18 columns in sql

Comment: can you add a client statistic screenshot? it would look like this http://www.sqlfreelancer.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SQL-Server-Client-Statistics-2.png

Comment: @fredou how can i get client statistics tab in output window

Comment: on the toolbar: https://www.brentozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/sql-editor-toolbar.jpg

Comment: @fredou updated the screenshot above

Comment: Looking very simple query.  Use sale profiler to check query. Add index on table,  you will get significant performance improvement

Comment: @Pankaj we are using views. let me  think about indexed views implementation

Comment: Do you really need all 42000 rows x 18 columns serialized into managed memory. What is the use case of displaying all that data to the user? Consider using pagination with Skip(pagesize*pages).Take(pagesize) etc in the query and just show the user meaningful data in the grid.

Comment: @Janne I need all the rows in memory but am not displaying all the rows to user. Only few records are displayed to user. But am using 42000 records for other operation

Comment: I would suggest trying to make the heavier operation on the sql server if possible. For computation the sql server will provide far better results than loading all to managed memory and then doing the operation in memory.

Comment: pasted more code you are doing something wrong.

Comment: to rule out bad coding and just check where the problem is... try new-ing up a context instead of reusing an old 1... maybe that one has a weird life span

Comment: Is the 2 minute measurement only the EF call or is it for the entire request? You might want to [check the generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx) to make sure it's not doing something funny. You can log that info by setting the log property in your DbContext's constructor. `Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsNoTracking()` as shown below.

```
this.db.progamview.Where(x => x.pId== 6 && x.qId== 12 && x.RId== 20151 && x.cId== 
102).AsNoTracking();
```

[**AsNoTracking()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)

**Update :** [**Performance Considerations for EF 6**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Comment: please see the **Update** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add indexes in databases. 
If you use code first you can add [Index] attribute.

Comment: @Wojtpls we are using db first approach. We have views create already, just we are calling the views from entityframework

Comment: If you're using database first,  you can use view as table.  It would give u best performance compare to link query

Comment: @PankajRawat we are using views only

Comment: If you are using views, your query should not take extra time.  Did u check with sql profiler?

Comment: @Pankaj problem only in fron-end not back-end.In Sql server it is running quickly

Comment: @Siva sometimes EF generates very complex query for simple linq statement that is why I suggest to check with sql profiler.